# Trying to initialize a list, getting __init__ type error

Tags: python-3.x, list, init

When I try to run an iteration of my Player object, I get this error: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'player' and 'number'.

My confusion lies in the idea that I did not think I needed to provide an argument for 'player' and 'number' because I am only trying to show the entire starting-players list. Here is my relevant code:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, player, number):
        self.player = player
        self.number = number
        self.starting_players = []

    def player_build(self):
        for p in ["Player"]:
            for n in range(1, 5):
                self.starting_players.append(Player(p, n))
                print('{} {}'.format(self.player, self.number))

    def show(self):
        for s in self.starting_players:
            s.show()
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback of your exception. It should tell you exactly where you're making the inappropriate call to `Player`. I suspect you're trying to create an instance to call `player_build` on, but you're not passing in the required paramters. I don't think your class design makes much sense, you should really use a separate class to collect several players together (and the `starting_players` attribute and `player_build` method should live in that collection). That is, unless you're wanting to arrange your players in a tree of some kind...

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do, yes. I'm still not sure why I have to create another class to do that, but it seems to make sense seeing as how my other two classes (not shown in this problem) are 'card' and 'deck'.

Answer (score 0):

If you define:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, player, number):
        ...
```

Then in order to initialize, you must do:

```
player1 = Player('John', 14)
```

To be honest, you are better off defining a new class, `class Team` and having it contain a number of players, `class Player`.